# I can't see or operate the smoke in my scene, why? (Simulate a smoke machine) blender 2.90

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, effects

I can't visualize the smoke correctly, I have performed all the steps and seen some tutorials and the other question here; both as a quick effect and manually generating a domain, after having performed the bake etc ..and if I try to orient it i can see a few traces of smoke both in render and in in viewport.
So the question are :

**1**. How do I control the smoke flow? orientation, leakage, power, quantity. I would like to simulate a smoke machine

**2**. Do I need to set some more parameters? Where , what?

ps. also in this render it seems that some textures have turned black, why? i used CUDA and optix denoising + denoising data, 256 samples, 256tiles.

RENDER VIEW

[image]

RENDER
[image]

GIF

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How smoke renders has to do also with the material for the domain. Please add an image showing what you have there.

Comment: I thought I put it on.

Comment: The nodes for the material used in the smoke domain?

Comment: sorry, i used the default material of a quick effects, shouldn't you see the same?(the smoke)